# How do I stop CORS from rejecting my Lambda-Proxy that I create in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

```
{
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PUT,OPTIONS"
}
```

originally I was using this since my API is a PUT request but it kept saying that one of my header fields (called access) was being rejected.

I then did this but to no avail.

```
{
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "access",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PUT,OPTIONS"
}
```

Comment: Add the header to the allowed headers, not to the allowed origin.

Answer (score 1):

You must put your header to [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, access
```